# In typescript, is it possible to infer that an interface optional properties have been defined from declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with hundreds of optional properties from a 3rd party library. (chartjs related for the context).
I want to find out if Typescript could infer that the optional properties that were defined when declaring the variable are not optional anymore, without too much hassle.

In my specific case, the amount of properties is big and using solutions like pick<> is less than ideal.

Example

```js
interface IMyInterface {
  prop1?: number[]
  //... 100's of optional props
}

const myObject: IMyInterface = {
  prop1: [1, 2]
  // some props are defined, some are not
}

myObject.prop1.slice(0, 1) // error: prop1 is possibly 'undefined'
```

I know I can extend the interface like:

```js
interface IMyNewInterface extends IMyInterface {
  prop1: number[]
}
```

Which is fine with a couple of properties but we are talking 100's and there must be a smarter way to do this.

Something like:

```js
const myObject: WhatIDeclareIsNotOptional<IMyInterface> = {
  prop1: [1, 2]
}

myObject.prop1.slice(0, 1) // no error
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to use the `satisfies` operator in 4.9:

```
interface IMyInterface {
  prop1?: number[]
}

const myObject = {
  prop1: [1, 2]
} satisfies IMyInterface 

myObject.prop1.slice(0, 1)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCerzXk5AbwFgAoZZABygHtKBGAfgC5kQBXAWwCNoBtALpkAvmTIIaIAM5hknTAHluAKwgJZAXiJkK1OvVZ96AGmQAmIaWHIpcMMCkxgEKWiw5IsRCjGl5S1XUAOj0GIKkAG2AkAAoABlN6AEpkIA)

You could also do it with a type annotation if you `Pick` and `Require` the properties you are interested in:

```
interface IMyInterface {
  prop1?: number[]
  prop2?: number[]
  prop3?: number[]
}

const myObject: IMyInterface & Required<Pick<IMyInterface, 'prop1' | 'prop2'>> = {
  prop1: [1, 2],
  prop2: [1, 2],
}

myObject.prop1.slice(0, 1)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCerzXk5AbwFgAoZZABygHtKBGAfgC5kQBXAWwCNoBtALpkK1OgCYWbLryiDhVWpQDMkjj35DSAXzJkENEAGcwyTpgDy3AFYQEYVhmy5YiFADJkAJQgBHdsCgIABMAHgAFYAQAaxDHHEgXJAAaZAByUQZU5AAfNIyxVIA+QuQAXiJ5DPpWPnoUsQEkysUxGrrkBqbtXVIzSxs7ADoqwcMAG0iIAAoABhT6AEpkIA)

You could also use a function to infer the picked keys:

```
function make<K extends keyof IMyInterface>(o: Required<Pick<IMyInterface, K>>) {
  return o;
}
const myObject = make({
  prop1: [1, 2],
  prop2: [],
})

myObject.prop1.slice(0, 1)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCerzXk5AbwFgAoZZABygHtKBGAfgC5kQBXAWwCNoBtALpkK1OgCYWbLryiDhVWpQDMkjj35DSAXzJkY7EAjDAaIZJzgBrCAB4A0sggAPSCAAmAZ2TXMNGGiwcSFhECAA+AAoaVgAlCABHdmAoCDcbAAVgBEsbDGxcEKQAGmQ7MLCASiJ5FLB2KDMaAG4yHVIEUw8wc0wAeW4AKwgjZABecysICJJyBTp6Vj56ErEBIvlRSjFFtdaK3VJOPsHhsAA6TfozjwAbLKmABhL6KqA)

Comment: I wanted to avoid pick because of the amount of properties involved. Regarding satisfies, which I didn't know, it looks like it sets all the types of the props to "never" if I don't put a value initially.

```
const myObject = {
  prop1: [] // No actual number in it yet
} satisfies IMyInterface 


myObject.prop1 // prop1 type is never[] instead of number[]
myObject.prop1.push(1) // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

Comment: @Kev The `never` part is unfortunate with `satisfies`. It sitll works if you don't want to mutate the value after or you can use and `as` on the empty arrays. I also added a version that uses a function to infer the icked keys

Comment: The reason for adding elements to the array afterwards is because, in the bigger picture, this object is an initial state for a reduce function that will populate its properties (filling arrays etc)

Comment: @Kev I understand. Don't think there are better options though